# SecureBlackBox - does TElSimpleSFTPClient.UploadStream automatically create folders if they don't exist? How to suppress?

Tags: c#, sftp

I am working on a C# project that connects to an SFTP server to upload a file.  Which folder to upload to is a configurable setting.  If the folder doesn't exist, it should fail.

However, I have been informed that, instead of failing, it is automatically creating the folder on the SFTP server.  There's no 'create a folder' logic in either my code or the in-house library wrapper.  Is it something that SecureBlackBox does, and if so then is there any way I can suppress this behaviour?  Or is it down to the SFTP server setup?

Comment: SecureBlackBox is now owned by /n Software

Comment: Your comment on the answer said "n/ Software" so I wondered which was correct!  But I've just found it online and it's /n: https://www.nsoftware.com/

Answer (score 3):

Indeed the folder structure is created if it doesn't exist. The component assumes that if you specify the directory structure, you want the operation to succeed, not to fail.

You can check whether the folder exists and fail if it doesn't. The method for this is available in the SFTP client (FolderExists if memory serves).

BTW support for products of EldoS Corporation is provided via the [Forum](https://www.eldos.com/forum/) and [HelpDesk](https://www.eldos.com/helpdesk/) on EldoS site. StackOverflow is probably not very efficient as it's not actively monitored and I have only accidentally come across your question.

Comment: I'm surprised about this.  If I try to save a file in a typical application, it will complain if the folder I try to save into doesn't exist, rather than silently creating the folder.  I haven't experimented with this aspect of different file I/O APIs but have always imagined them to be the same.

Still, I'm curious about whether the library does extra work to check whether the folder exists before attempting the upload, as opposed to (for example) attempting the upload and then creating the folder and trying again if it fails.

Anyhow, thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: @Stewart We could implement the component in both ways - to fail or to create the directories.  Most users expect the component not to fail but create directories so we have chosen to do what was requested. To answer your question, the component checks the directory existence prior to attempting to open the file for writing. Maybe we'll add a component-level option to not check the directories.

Comment: EldoS Corporation no longer exists.  n/ Software took it over.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'Callback Coming back to this (hadn't realised how long it's been!) I would imagine that most people, if they've made a typo when telling software what folder to upload to, would expect the software to alert them to the fact that the folder doesn't exist, rather than silently creating the folder with the mistyped name.

Comment: @Stewart SecureBlackbox is a library and a very flexible one. There exist different design approaches, and SecureBlackbox doesn't make guesses - it does what the developer specifies. If you would like to see different behavior - please, submit your suggestion to support. I think, those methods now have flags that let you tell the component how to behave, and if some flag is missing, it's easy to add one. I don't deal with SecureBlackbox now, so I don't know the current state of development (besides knowing that the v.2020 release is around the corner).